# How many of these modified harmonic series converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

In my Analysis course we showed that the harmonic series diverged but the alternating harmonic series converges. This got me thinking:

> How many sequences $(a_n)$ where $|a_n|=1/n$ are there such that $\sum
>  a_n$ converges?

There are quite clearly at least countably many (modify the sign of the $n$th term of the alternating series and we still have convergence), so my question is really whether there are uncountably many such sequences. I should think so but I am failing to find a good reason.

Answer (score 2):

We can freely change signs on the terms of the shape $\frac{1}{2^k}$ without affecting convergence.  So there are  continuum-many such sequences.

Comment: Thanks, that is a clever observation.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Out of interest can something like this always be done given a conditionally convergent series $\sum a_n?$ i.e. can we always find a subsequence $(x_n)$ of $(a_n)$ (in this case $x_n=2^{-n}$) such that $\sum x_n$ is absolutely convergent?

Comment: Yes, because if the series $\sum a_n$ converges, then the terms have limit $0$. So we can find an $n_1$ such that $|a_{n_1}|\lt \frac{1}{2}$. And then we can find an $n_2\gt n_1$ such that $|a_{n_2}|\lt \frac{1}{2^2}$. And then we can find an $n_3$ such that $\dots$.